# Unable to render objects with glDrawElements in OpenGLES2

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0

I am working on a simple OpenGLES test application in XCode (for iOS) and I am trying to render basic geometry using glVertexPointer and glDrawElements. So far, nothing is being rendered regardless of my camera's position and I am out of ideas as to what I could be doing wrong.

Update: Tried using framebuffer object to draw the geometry but it keeps failing to create one. Here's some additional code to generate the framebuffer object and renderbuffer objects:

```
- (BOOL)createFrameBuffer {
glGenFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[self.context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer*)((GLKView *)self.view).layer];
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);

glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH_OES, &backingWidth);
glGetRenderbufferParameterivOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT_OES, &backingHeight);

glGenRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES, backingWidth, backingHeight);
glFramebufferRenderbufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_OES, GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, depthRenderbuffer);

if(glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES) {
    NSLog(@"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES));
    return NO;
}

return YES;
}

- (void)destroyFrameBuffer {
glDeleteFramebuffersOES(1, &viewFramebuffer);
viewFramebuffer = 0;
glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
viewRenderbuffer = 0;

if(depthRenderbuffer) {
    glDeleteRenderbuffersOES(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
    depthRenderbuffer = 0;
}
}
```

Here's the drawing function being called:

```
-(void)glkView: (GLKView *)view drawInRect: (CGRect)rect {

float vertices[18] = {
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f
};

short indices[6] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 1, 3
};

Byte colors[24] = {
    255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255
};

[self destroyFrameBuffer];
if([self createFrameBuffer] == NO) {
    return;
}

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: self.context];

glBindFramebufferOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES, viewFramebuffer);

glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

//glViewport(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
glViewport(0, 0, backingWidth, backingHeight);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(_rotation, 1, 1, 1); // rotate object around
glTranslatef(0, 0, -8);

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0, colors);

// draw
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 2, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);

glBindRenderbufferOES(GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES, viewRenderbuffer);
[self.context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER_OES];
}
```

Note that this is with all effects (lighting, shaders, etc) disabled. Also this code is being called from within the view controller that inherits GLKViewController.

Comment: Don't you need to generate a colorbuffer and a framebuffer in IOS even if you use es 1.1 ?

Comment: Tried to create a framebuffer object but glCheckFramebufferStatusOES(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_OES) keeps failing whenever I try to make one.

Comment: Try again, you should make a framebuffer object and a Renderbuffer object and attach the renderbuffer obj to framebuffer obj. With out them, you can't run any opengl program on IOS

Comment: I see you updated already . I am not sure it is working but try before  calling glFramebufferRenderbuffer() call glbindframebuffer() again

Comment: I have the exact same problem.